# How to rearrange 2 columns so that each combination of unique pairs is ordered by the first column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
data <- data.frame(GameNum = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                   Team1 = c("TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamA", 
                             "TeamB", "TeamB", "TeamB", "TeamC"),
                   Team2 = c("TeamB", "TeamC", "TeamD", "TeamD", 
                             "TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamC", "TeamA"),
                   Team1_Win = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))
# whether Team1 won or not
```

Each row is a different game. Some teams have multiple matches against each other. Sometimes TeamA is in Team1 and sometimes TeamA is Team2. I want to manipulate this data so that I have ALL of TeamA in column Team1 with all of its matches. Then I want to move on to TeamB with ALL of its matches (EXCEPT for TeamA) and so on for TeamC,TeamD etc.

Essentially I would like for it to look like this:

```
data <- data.frame(GameNum = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                   Team1 = c("TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamA", 
                             "TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamB", "TeamA"),
                   Team2 = c("TeamB", "TeamC", "TeamD", "TeamD", 
                             "TeamB", "TeamB", "TeamC", "TeamC"),
                   Team1_Win = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

Where Team1_Win changes when I rearrange the column.

How would I do this in R or Python? SQL?? Even pseudocode is fine. I just don't know where to start. I appreciate any advice. Thank you.

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What's with the asterisks? Should TeamB be treated differently with **TeamB** ?

Comment: You should probably remove the asterisks: I think they are supposed to highlight certain values, but they look like part of the data which is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a quick solution using `dplyr` and a few `ifelse()` conditions:

```
### Your input dataframe
data <- data.frame(GameNum = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                   Team1 = c("TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamA", 
                             "TeamB", "TeamB", "TeamB", "TeamC"),
                   Team2 = c("TeamB", "TeamC", "TeamD", "TeamD", 
                             "TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamC", "TeamA"),
                   Team1_Win = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))

### Generating new columns for Team1 and Team2 and checking whether the sequence need to be reversed

data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Team1_new = ifelse(Team1 > Team2, Team2, Team1), 
                Team2_new = ifelse(Team1 > Team2, Team1, Team2)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Team1_Win_new = ifelse(Team1 == Team1_new, Team1_Win, !Team1_Win)) %>%
  dplyr::select(GameNum, Team1_new, Team2_new, Team1_Win_new) %>%
  arrange(Team1_new, Team2_new)
```

Output:

```
  GameNum Team1_new Team2_new Team1_Win_new
1       1     TeamA     TeamB             1
2       5     TeamA     TeamB             0
3       6     TeamA     TeamB             1
4       2     TeamA     TeamC             0
5       8     TeamA     TeamC             1
6       3     TeamA     TeamD             1
7       4     TeamA     TeamD             1
8       7     TeamB     TeamC             1
```

***NOTE*** that in your original database if your sequence is not alphabetical (like here) then you need to convert the team names to `factor` class with the levels you desire.